# Error when compiling code?

Tags: python, gcc, compilation, linker, g++

I encountered a error when installing python twisted package.

```
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/T/Twisted/Twisted-12.0.0.tar.bz2#md5=cf49a8676c21c50faf1b42b528049471
Processing Twisted-12.0.0.tar.bz2
Running Twisted-12.0.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-hEuJVt/Twisted-12.0.0/egg-dist-tmp-kPGrsY
/usr/bin/ld: crtbeginS.o: No such file: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

When I compiled other c++ programs this error happened too. Have anyone faced the same problem? I googled a lot but found nothing works for me.

Comment: @Blender: If `gcc` got far enough to run `ld`, I'd say at least the `gcc` executable (if not the rest of GCC) is installed.

Comment: gcc version 4.4.3 is installed

Comment: what happens when you type `gcc --print-file-name crtbeginS.o` .. do you get `/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/crtbeginS.o`? Is this file present on your system? If you can find it, then some path is not set right, if it's missing all together, you may want to re-install your compiler